# selecting Raphael.js map path to Qtip tooltip

Tags: jquery-selectors, svg, raphael, qtip, tooltip

I am simply trying to select country paths to trigger tooltips.  I suspect I am not referring to an accurate element in the svg file.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('worldmap.shapes.US').qtip({ content: { text: 'Name: United States<br>Capital: Jefferson City'    },
        style: {
            background: '#000000',
            color: '#ffffff',
            border: { width: 6, radius: 3, color: '#ff0000' }
        },
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'topRight',
                tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
            }
        }
    });
```

});

Here is how the svg file is formatted:

```
  worldmap = {
  shapes: {
 AE:     "M604.196,161.643l0.514-0.129l0,0.772l2.188-0.386l2.189,0l1.672,0.129l1.803-1.802l2.058-1.802l1.674-1.673l0.518,0.900l0.385,2.189l-1.417,0l-0.258,1.802l0.517,0.386l-1.159,0.515l-0.129,1.029l-0.773,1.159l0,1.030l-0.514,0.644l-8.110-1.416l-1.031-2.704l0.127,0.643z",
```

it's a .js file

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see how you draw your raphael.js path. If you're doing something like that:

```
my_path = paper.path("M 100,200 L ... z");
```

You than have to use the .node() method on your raphael path object (my_path). That gives you a ref to the DOM object which you can than use.

```
$(my_path.node).qtip({ ... })
```

See e.g. http://www.itbrigadeinc.com/post/2012/05/03/Tooltips-in-Raphael.aspx